# Vaadin, Nginx. unsaved data

Tags: nginx, vaadin, vaadin7

See image below of vaadin 7, nginx. What could be wrong?
[image: screen shot]

[web.xml](https://gist.github.com/dream-x/d966f3cb1b00335e9c88)

sample config:

```vaadin
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     crm.komrus.com;
  root            /home/deploy/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/komruscrm;

  proxy_cache one;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/komruscrm/;
  }
}
```

Comment: Pls share your web.xml config for additional troubleshooting

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dream-x/d966f3cb1b00335e9c88

Comment: I don't need your entire project, share your web.xml... I'm not allowed to download some stuff on my system

Comment: Usually this just means that your session has expired... What is the session timeout in your servlet engine? When does the message show up?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems (because you don't provide enough info about your problem) you are using nginx as reverse proxy for tomcat/jboss/jetty, and you are deploying a Vaadin application in it.

Just when you enter in the application, session expired message appears.

I had this problem 3 months ago. In my escenario Nginx was 1.0 and Vaadin 7.0+. The issue comes because of the cookies. I know that nginx must set or rewrite something in the cookies, but, you must set it manually in nginx.conf file, else, you will get that error.

Sadly, in my nginx version I wasn't able to pass cookies in the right way, so, I wasn't able to deploy my application under that scenario.

After some issues, I've decided to use Apache's reverse proxy, and never saw that issue again. Hope you can write a rule that enables to pass the cookies in the right way.

**EDIT:** I remembered this post [How to rewrite the domain part of Set-Cookie in a nginx reverse proxy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/278319/how-to-rewrite-the-domain-part-of-set-cookie-in-a-nginx-reverse-proxy), this is the case!